# System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save() causes a full harddrive

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I got a problem and need help. I need to save a XML file, about 400MB. I'm using `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save()` for this. Normally it is no problem, but sometimes i got a strange behavoir, `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save()` did save the XML-Data in an endless loop in the same XML, till the harddrive is fuil. Taking the same XML-Data once again, and there is no problem, everything works fine. So it wasn't possilbe to reproduce this behavior, till now!

I got a new server, and now this is the only result i'm getting, everytime System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save() is called! It is absolutly reproducable...here is the new environement

- .Net Framework 4 (also 4.5)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1
- 32 GB Ram
- 64 Bit
- all updates are installed

Thanks for help!

---

Here is the code snippet:

```
xmlImp = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null),
    new XDocumentType("Hotelstamm", null, "hotel.dtd", null),
    HotelStamm);

string pathUTF8 = path.Replace(".xml", "-utf8.xml");
try 
{ 
    xmlImp.Save(pathUTF8);
} 
catch (IOException) 
{
}
```

Edit:

The Problem was that we created the Xml-Structure in multiple threads and the .Add-Method of XElement is not thread-safe. If it is called in multiple threads it damages the Xml-Stucture and the Xml starts to get infinite.

The Problem was that the application runs fine in about 95% on our old server. But on the new one it had only a 5% chance to succed.
On the old server  a sinpmle loop with 3 tries made it work. But now with locking it works fine.

Comment: If its reproducable, tell us how to reproduce it. Presumably, you're not asserting the any `XDocument.Save()` call on a machine with that specification will exhibit this behaviour, or are you?

Comment: I'm pessimistic that this is a generic issue that would effect all machines with that specification, I'd guess its much more likely a problem with that specific build. However, I don't have experience of saving 400MB XML files, with `XDocument.Save()` on a machines with that specification. Therefore, I'm unable to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: @Jodrell: Well, all the servers are almost the same: alle 2008 R2, all 32 GB Ram, all 64Bit. All of them running the same runtime version.
Here is the code snippet:

`XmlImp = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null),
                new XDocumentType("Hotelstamm", null, "hotel.dtd", null),
                HotelStamm);

            string pathUTF8 = path.Replace(".xml", "-utf8.xml");

            try
            {
                XmlImp.Save(pathUTF8);
            }
            catch (IOException ioEx)`

Comment: So, if just one exhibits the problem, whats the difference or, do they all do it?

Comment: what datype is `HotelStamm`? does it contain a hierarchical structure with parent-child associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-examining the code, I notice you are using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338517.aspx) of the XDocument ctor.

If the `HotelStamm`, variable you pass to the constructor contains a complex cyclical relationship, it may be that it cannot be finitely represented in hierachical XML.

You could try enumerating `xmlImp.Descendants()` and see if you get the same race behaviour.

If so, you have a problematic cyclical relationship you need to simpify. Note, this would have nothing directly to do with the spec of the machine the code is run on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in deed it was the XML Strukture. SOLVED!

Comment: The Problem was that we created the Xml-Structure in multiple Threads and the .Add-Method of XElement is not thread-safe. If it is called in multiple threads it damages the Xml-Stucture and the Xml starts to get infinite.